# SharePoint Online Theme not displayed for guests - "Cannot find theme color: Light1"

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme

I have a SharePoint site which is themed, but when an authenticated guest user logs in to the site, they get a black bar at the top.

In the browser console, I get the message "Cannot find theme color: Light1" from theming.js.

Any thoughts?
Many thanks,
D.

Answer (score 1):

I assume all previous users can see the correct theme.

Please check the permissions for the file. Somewhere on the way between the site and the file (e.g. at the library level where the file is located) there is broken permission inheritance.

The issue you are describing should affect all NEWLY invited users to the site. It happens because old users had and still have permissions to the file.

You broke the inheritance probably while creating the theme and you wanted to prevent users from editing it. Sorry, but that's the side-effect :( They have to have rights to at least view (pls correct if wrong here) the .js file.

One of the ways to check elements with unique permissions (items, libraries, files) is to go to the Site Settings>Site permissions and view items with unique permissions:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was thinking that but not sure which file and where to find it/set permissions for it. I.e. I assume the Light 1 is referencing the .spcolor file? I can see that under themes but not sure where it is in a list to check permissions?

Comment: When you are in the Themes you should see a Ribbon like in any other Sp library. Click on Library>Library Settings>Permissions for this document library and in the top left corner you will have either 'Stop Inheriting Permissions' (OK) or 'Delete unique permissions' (broken inheritance)